# SSRS not sending scheduled email to specific contact

Tags: sql-server, database-mail, ssrs-2012

I have a specific contact for my SSRS subscriptions that does not receive any mail from SSRS.
her email is an organization email, everyone else including me are getting emails but only that specific user doesn't.

I checked ssrs logs and i see it was sent successfully:

> notification!WindowsService_0!1aa0!12/05/2019-14:15:23::
>    i INFO: Notification af94f76f-d236-4ffb-b4e7-8450d206f654 completed.
>     Success: True, Status: Mail sent to contact1@organization.com;contact2@organization.com;, 
>   DeliveryExtension: Report Server Email, Report: Notables Report (Euro),
>    Attempt 0

This is what i tried so far:

1. recreating the subscription
2. recreating reports
3. creating a simple report with no attached files
4. checking all her mail folders and junk mail
5. restarting SSRS services
6. IT team checked the mail server shes not receiving the mails they say it doesn't even go through the mailing server.
7. She does get regular mails
8. sending mail from the same server via SQL works.
9. when sending email to a group she belongs too she still doesn't get mail.

it happens with all reports in that server
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question shouldn't be posted here even if it is related to SSRS.

IMHO and according the comments it seems that the SMTP service used by SSRS is miss-configured.

Take a deep look at SPF record in your DNS to ensure it belongs to your domain. Some mail servers have an strong spam-filter activated to ensure all received mails are good and belonging to the mail sender domain. Among other spam-filters.

You can use some (online) tools to check your mail server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the problem was the exchange server itself..
IT fixed it and the mailing from SSRS worked